# Cannot select text whilst scrolling down the page in Firefox

Tags: 11.10, firefox

Selection with scrolling in firefox on Ubuntu 11.10(gnome-shell or unity):

Selection text when scrolling down the page is not feasible (only up).

In the chrome browser such bug is not available.
This bug appears when firefox window is maximized(as usualy).
 Any ideas?

This bug still exists in Gnome 3.14.1 in Firefox 38...

Comment: Just tested this and it works, so I'm flagging this for closure as [too localized](http://askubuntu.com/faq#close).

Comment: I don't know how it works with you but on my system it doesn't works. This bug exists already a year after gnome 3 release in all linux distributions.

Comment: I have good news and bad news. It was fixed, and broke again. It's [Bug#744580](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/744580) on Launchpad, (where you already commented). As a bug report, it should still be closed but as '[off topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/226/are-bug-reports-suitable-for-this-site)', not too localized. Hope this works again soon, sorry I can't help you with a fix yet.

Comment: Too bad this is closed... I'm experiencing this too, it is very annoying, and this is the very first google hit when searching for 'selection scroll down firefox ubuntu'.